# Why can guards still see me when I use the Become Ethereal shout?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm using the Become Ethereal shout to sneak past some guards, but they instantly walk up to me and give me "You've committed crimes" speech.

Why? How can I fix this? I'm on the PC.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Become Ethereal does not make you invisible, rather it stops you taking damage until it runs out or you take an action.

The invisibility spell or the [Shadow Stone](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Shadow_Stone) near Riften will make you invisible and able to sneak past the guards.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm used to the "Ethereal Plane" meaning you are also on a different plane, and unable to be seen.

Comment: You're welcome. That shout is also really useful for when you want to jump off tall things without dying.

Answer (score 14):

The [Become Ethereal](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Become_Ethereal) shout does not make you invisible.  It only means you do not take or deal damage.

Comment: Why did this receive a down vote?

Comment: Odds are, someone didn't look at the timestamps.